# How rewrite DB::select to model with findOrFail in LARAVEL Controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, routes, controller

Hi i have REGION model but i dont know how rewrite this DB::select. I want it with findOrFail or something for ,,If i find this slug i show page if no i show 404

> My web.php route

```
Route::get('/turnaje/{slug}', [RegionController::class, 'show']);
```

> My Region Controller

```
public function show($slug)
{

    $regions = DB::select('select * from regions where slug = ?', [$slug]);
    $regions_list = DB::select('select * from regions');

    return view('tournaments.show', [
        'regions' => $regions,
        'regions_list' => $regions_list,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the model as a facade and write a similar query. I'm assuming you want an exception thrown when there is no region with that slug?

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $regions = Region::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $regions_list = Region::all();

    return view('tournaments.show', [
        'regions' => $regions,
        'regions_list' => $regions_list,
    ]);
}
```

You may want to handle the `ModelNotFoundException`

Comment: I was try it but in blade is ERROR i add other comment with description of the problem

Comment: Can you update the question with your error

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Changing route model binding form id to slug by defining `getRouteKeyName` function in your model:

```
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

2. Using `firstOrFail`:

   `Region::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();`